# Can a non-splittable link be split by a wild sphere?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let $L$ be a non-splittable link in $S^3$. Non-splittable means that there is no smooth embedding $s:S^2\to S^3\setminus L$ which splits $L$, i. e. such that both connected components of $S^3\setminus\operatorname{im}s$ intersect $L$.

The [Hopf link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_link) is an example.

> Proof. Let $l_1, l_2:S^1 \to S^3$ be two smooth embeddings with images $L_1$ and $L_2$, forming the Hopf link $L=L_1\sqcup L_2$, $s:S^2\to S^3\setminus L$ a smooth embedding which splits $L$, $B$ a connected component of $S^3\setminus \operatorname{im}s$. Suppose that $L_1\subset B$ and $L_2\cap B=\varnothing$. By Alexander's theorem, $B$ is homeomorphic to the 3-ball, so $l_1$ is contractible as a map to $B=B\setminus L_2$, hence contractible as a map to $S^3\setminus L_2$. This is a contradiction (for example, one can construct a retraction of $S^3\setminus L_2$ onto $L_1$, which is homeomorphic to $S^1$, so non-contractible).

Can there still be a *continuous* embedding $s:S^2\to S^3\setminus L$ which splits $L$? The analogue of Alexander's theorem is false for continuous embeddings, so the above proof doesn't work.

Comment: The wild sphere would be a positive distance away from the link, by compactness, so hopefully you can "smooth it out" while preserving injectivity... I think you want to use Dehn's lemma?

Comment: When s is a continuous embedding, $im s$ is a wild sphere. The closure of each connected component is called a crumpled cube. In dim 3, there is a reembedding theorem: For each crumpled cube C in $S^3$ and each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a reembedding $h$ of $C$ in $S^3$ moving points less than $\epsilon$ such that the closure of $S^3 - h(C)$ is a 3-cell. This is proved by Hosay and Lininger, independently.

Comment: For the particular case of the Hopf link, no. The complement of the Hopf link is homotopy equivalent to $(S^1)^2$ and thus has vanishing $\pi_2$, so any continuous map from an $S^2$ to the complement of the Hopf link can be contracted to a point without touching the Hopf link.

Comment: @Shijie Gu, thank you, this theorem seems to answer my question.

Comment: @David E Speyer, by the way, the complement of any non-splittable link in $S^3$ has vanishing higher homotopy groups (Papakyriakopoulos, On Dehn's lemma and the asphericity of knots, https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/papa.pdf). But I don't see how it solves the problem.

Comment: @igorf Maybe I am missing something. Let $L_1 \cup L_2$ be a nonsplittable link and let $S^2 \to S^3 \setminus (L_1 \cup L_2)$ be an embedding which supposedly splits the link. Choose a point $p$ not on the link. By the result you quote, I can contract the $S^2$ onto a tiny neighborhood of $p$ without passing through $L_1$ or $L_2$. But, once the $S^2$ is in that tiny neighborhood, $L_1$ and $L_2$ are on the same side of it, so they were on the same side from the start. (I am appealing to the Jordan separation theorem in order to talk about "sides". This is still correct for wild spheres.)

Comment: Oh, maybe the issue is that, since the $S^2$ passes through itself during the homotopy, it is confusing to think about sides. That might be right ... I'll leave this here and see if someone else thinks it is fixable.

Comment: No, I think I am right. This is getting too long for comments, so I am going to leave an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L_1 \cup L_2$ be a nonsplittable link in $S^3$, and let $\phi : S^2 \to S^3 \setminus (L_1 \cup L_2)$ be an embedding of a $2$-sphere. We want to show that the $S^2$ does not separate $L_1$ from $L_2$.

Choose a points $p_1$ and $p_2$ on $L_1$ and $L_2$, so $S^3 \setminus \{ p_1, p_2 \} \cong S^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ and $H_2(S^3 \setminus \{ p_1, p_2 \} ) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. The sphere $\phi(S^2)$ will separate $L_1$ from $L_2$ if and only if $\phi_{\ast}[S^2]$ is nontrivial in  $H_2(S^3 \setminus \{ p_1, p_2 \} )$.

The OP points me to a [paper of Papakyriakopoulos](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/papa.pdf) which proves that $\pi_2(S^3 \setminus (L_1 \cup L_2))$ is trivial. Therefore, there is a homotopy between $\phi$ and a constant map $S^2 \to S^3 \setminus (L_1 \cup L_2)$, with the homotopy staying within $S^3 \setminus (L_1 \cup L_2)$. But then, in particular, the homotopy stays within $S^3 \setminus \{ p_1, p_2 \}$, so the two homotopic maps induce that same map $H_2(S^2) \to H_2(S^3 \setminus \{ p_1, p_2 \} )$. So $\phi_{\ast}$ is zero on $H_2$, and thus $\phi(S^2)$ does not separate $p_1$ from $p_2$.

Comment: The "paper of Papakyriakopoulos" proves Dehn's lemma and the Sphere Theorem (which you are using). These are some of the most fundamental results in 3-manifold topology.

Comment: @HJRW Okay, you are talking about this sphere theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_theorem_(3-manifolds) , so ignore my previous comment. But, no, I am not. The OP's hypotheses give me an embedded sphere $\phi : S^2 \to S^3 \setminus (L_1 \cup L_2)$ and I am pointing out that condition that $\phi(S^2)$ seperates means that this represents a nontrivial class in $\pi_2(S^3 \setminus \{ p_1, p_2 \})$. The Sphere theorem is about "given a nontrivial class in $\pi_2$, is there an embedded sphere representing it?", not "given an embedded sphere, is its class in $\pi_2$ nontrivial?"

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: A total quibble -- the sphere theorem tells you that you that if $\pi_2$ is nontrivial, then there is an embedded sphere representing a nontrivial element in it.  It does not let you represent an arbitrary nontrivial element of $\pi_2$ by an embedded sphere, which is often not possible.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: we seem to be talking at cross purposes. Sorry if my original comment was confusing. Your answer explicitly uses the fact that an irreducible 3-manifold has trivial $\pi_2$. This is a standard consequence of the sphere theorem, which was proved by Papakyriakopoulos, so you're quite right to cite that paper. I'm just trying to point out that the formulation "a paper of Papakyriakopoulos which proves that..." makes it sound like some obscure result, when in fact it's one of the most fundamental results in the subject.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks.

Comment: @HJRW Okay, I get where you are coming from now.

Comment: I think I see what is going in -- the fact that non-splittable implies trivial $\pi_2$ is almost exactly the sphere theorem. (It is also provable by hand for the Hopf link.) The fact that trivial $\pi_2$ implies not splittable by wild spheres is at the level of Hatcher's book, and is what I explain in this answer.